# Is there any license requirement using mxnet model zoo?

Tags: model, zoo, mxnet

I think
Models listed on 
https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/model_zoo/
is free to use as basis of fine tuning. Am I right?
Is there any license problem or condition using these models (VGG16,ResidualNet152,etc)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. **[See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)** for details and the **[help]** for more.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-model-gallery

You can see it's licensed under CC0

Comment: Thank you for providing me the information. I have confirmed that it's licensed under CC0.